# What's wrong with this else if statement?

Tags: java

```
package javaPackage;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);

        int test1Score;
        int test2Score;

        System.out.print("Enter first test score:");
        test1Score = imput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second test score:");
        test2Score = imput.nextInt();

        if((test1Score > 90) && (test2Score > 90))
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou are promoted to manager");
        }

        else if((test1Score > 90) || (test2Score >90))
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou are promoted to supervisor");
        }

        else if(!(test1Score>90))
        {

            System.out.println("\nYou are not promoted");
        }

    }

}
```

Everything seems to work. However on the second else if statement if I type in 89 as first test score I get the output for the first else if.  I should inform me "you are not promoted".  It seems to only check the else if with the logical OR.
I'm just now learning java.  I must not be seeing something.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but it might be easier to write the last `if` statement as such: `else if(test1Score <= 90)` instead of using the `not` operator.

Comment: What are you putting for the second input?

Comment: At the second if `test1Score` doesn't matter if `test2Score` is > 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the second else if statemenr has a logic error. The > 90 should be < 90. Otherwise the statement is redundant. However consider making the second if else just an else in order to simplify and handle all of the other possible permutations.  Not to hard tio pick out here but when the code gets more complicated it can become harder to find these things. Hope this helps and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic depends on the values of two variables. You've only supplied one in your question description, so I assume that the second did not meet the conditions of the `AND` statement.

Both values must exceed 90 for the first conditional to result in TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it seems the logic did not make sense.  I am practicing the examples from a book called "My First in Java".  It seems this book is not written very well.
 I changed the second else if statement to:

else if(test1Score < 90 && test2Score <90){
        System.out.println("\nYou are not promoted");

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assumed that it should print
1. "You are promoted to manager" only if both the test scores are greater than 90
2. "You are promoted to supervisor" if any of the two test scores is greater than 90
3. "You are not promoted" if both the test scores are lesser than 91

So you just have to include 'test2Score' in your second else if condition as shown below.

```
if((test1Score > 90) && (test2Score > 90))
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou are promoted to manager");
        }

        else if((test1Score > 90) || (test2Score >90))
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou are promoted to supervisor");
        }

        else     //((test1Score <= 90) && (test2Score <= 90))
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou are not promoted");
        }
```

But if you want to print "You are not promoted" when test1Score <= 90 regardless the test2Score, you have to modify your if conditions accordingly.